USPS API the response of creating label is not JSON/XML, anyone know how to deserialize the data?
I'm using USPS NEW API(https://developer.usps.com/api/71) to create domestic label, the response is not standard JSON/XML,it's some data with headers(I don't know what's the format is),see below
--z-zSV9BXZtRNip-8GHCvJoED
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="labelMetadata"

{"labelAddress":{"streetAddress":"2512 3N","secondaryAddress":"","city":"APPLE","state":"WI","ZIPCode":"54913","firstName":"Dan","lastName":"Run","ignoreBadAddress":true},"routingInformation":"42054913","trackingNumber":"9200190359099201038375","postage":0.00,"extraServices":[{"name":"USPS Tracking","price":0.0,"SKU":"DXTU0EXXXCX0000"}],"zone":"05","commitment":{"name":"3 Days","scheduleDeliveryDate":"2024-09-27"},"weightUOM":"LB","weight":0.22,"dimensionalWeight":0.0,"fees":[],"bannerText":"USPS TRACKING # USPS Ship","constructCode":"C03","SKU":"DUXP0XXXUC05040"}
--z-zSV9BXZtRNip-8GHCvJoED
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="labelImage.pdf"; name="labelImage"

JVBERi0xLjQKJaqrrK0KMSAwIG9iago8PAovUHJvZHVjZXIgKEFwYWNoZSBGT1AgVmVyc2lvbiBTVk46IFBERiBUcmFuc2NvZGVyIGZvciBCYXRpaykKL0NyZWF0aW9uRGF0ZSAoRDoyMDI0MDkyNDA3NTg1OFopCj4+CmVuZG9iagoyIDAgb2JqCjw8CiAgL04gMwogIC9MZW5ndGggMyAwIFIKICAvRmlsdGVyIC9GbGF0ZURlY29kZQo.......
--z-zSV9BXZtRNip-8GHCvJoED--

You can tell the data before '--z-zSV9BXZtRNip-8GHCvJoED' is a header with tracking info(JSON data), and after '--z-zSV9BXZtRNip-8GHCvJoED' is a header with PDF(base64)
Any one can know what the data format is, and how to deserialize it?
I need a way to deserialize this kind of data like normally we do to deserialize JSON/XML data


The default media type of the response has multiple parts. Setting the Accept header to either application/json or application/xml will only affect the metadata part of the multipart response.

try to add ["Accept":"application/json"] to your request header

No, you'll still only get mutli-part data back, with the first part being of type application/json.  If you want a JSON-only response, set it to "application/vnd.usps.labels+json".  I'm not sure how reliable this will be in the future though, as the returned JSON doesn't match the documented format (the members that should be under labelMetaData are returned as members of the top-level document.)

Short answer: Make your request with an Accept: application/vnd.usps.labels+json header and the API will return a JSON payload to you without the multi-part nonsense.
Notice that today's documentation has the wrong schema for the JSON response.  I did hear back from USPS' developer support and they will be correcting that documentation in the future.  (The documentation shows members under a labelMetaData object when in actuality they are returned as members of the top-level document.)
POST https://api.usps.com/labels/v3/label HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/vnd.usps.labels+json
Authorization: Bearer [redacted]
Content-Length: 1086
Content-Type: application/json
X-Payment-Authorization-Token: [redacted]

{
  "imageInfo" : {
    "imageType" : "ZPL203DPI",
    "labelType" : "4X6LABEL",
    "receiptOption" : "NONE",
    "suppressPostage" : true,
    "suppressMailDate" : true,
    "returnLabel" : false
  },
  "toAddress" : {
    ...
  },
  "fromAddress" : {
    ...
  },
  "packageDescription" : {
    "weight" : 0.5,
    "length" : 5.0,
    "width" : 5.0,
    "height" : 4.0,
    "mailClass" : "PRIORITY_MAIL",
    "processingCategory" : "MACHINABLE",
    "destinationEntryFacilityType" : "NONE",
    "extraServices" : [ 920 ],
    "mailingDate" : "2024-12-16",
    "rateIndicator" : "SP"
  }
}

{
  "labelImage": "<base64>",
  "labelAddress": {
    ...
  },
  "routingInformation": "...",
  "trackingNumber": "...",
  "postage": 6.17,
  "extraServices": [
    {
      "name": "USPS Tracking",
      "price": 0,
      "SKU": "DXTP0EXXXCX0000"
    }
  ],
  "zone": "02",
  "commitment": {
    "name": "2 Days",
    "scheduleDeliveryDate": "2024-12-19"
  },
  "weightUOM": "LB",
  "weight": 0.5,
  "dimensionalWeight": 0,
  "fees": [],
  "bannerText": "USPS TRACKING # USPS Ship",
  "retailDistributionCode": "03",
  "serviceTypeCode": "055",
  "constructCode": "C03",
  "SKU": "DPXX0XXXX102005"
}

